# FileHelpers FieldConverter doesn't get called if value is whitespace

Tags: c#, filehelpers, fixed-length-record

I am trying to parse a file using FileHelpers. I need to map fields to a KeyValuePair and for a few of these fields, there is a mapping if the string in the file is whitespace. However, my custom FieldConverter's FieldToString method does not seem to be called when the string from the file is whitespace. I want it to be called though!

Here is my field definition:

```
[FieldFixedLength(1)]
[FieldTrim(TrimMode.Right)]
[FieldConverter(typeof(AreYouOneOfTheFollowingConverter))]
public KeyValuePair<int, string>? AreYouOneOfTheFollowing;
```

Here is my converter ([case " ":] is never hit):

```
public class AreYouOneOfTheFollowingConverter : ConverterBase
{
    public override object StringToField(string from)
    {
        switch (from)
        {
            case "1":
                {
                    return new KeyValuePair<int, string>(1469, "Yes");
                }
            case " ":
                {
                    return new KeyValuePair<int, string>(1470, "No");
                }
            default:
                {
                    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(from))
                    {
                        return from;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new NotImplementedException();
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Ideas?

Comment: Just a guess, but I'm betting because you have the `FieldTrim` attribute the field is never just a space, but instead would be a empty string. Since the `FieldTrim` attribute is not part of the .Net Library, it's hard to validate.

Comment: I removed all of the `FieldTrim` attributes and it does not make a difference.

Comment: Leaving the field as `string` preserves the whitespace though. Is it just expected functionality for the FieldConverter to not check whitespaces?

Comment: Not sure but I just verified that is what happens. I tried some different attributes trying to force it to recognize the white space, but the engine converts the white space to null automatically. As you've already mentioned, you can use a `String` as the field and the white space will be preserved.

Answer (score 3):

`ConverterBase` has a virtual method you can override to control the automatic handling of white space.

```
public class AreYouOneOfTheFollowingConverter : ConverterBase
{
    protected override bool CustomNullHandling
    {
        /// you need to tell the converter not 
        /// to handle empty values automatically
        get { return true; } 
    }

    public override object StringToField(string from)
    {
         /// etc...
    }
}
```